# Almacenamiento de nombres, áreas y teléfonos en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Necesito un consejo, tengo tres tablas, una de empleados, una de áreas y una de teléfonos, mi intención es que en ésta última se almacenen los teléfonos tanto de los empleados como de las áreas, la cuestión es que no sé como relacionarlos, si fuera solo una tabla de empleados y la de teléfonos, agregaría el id del empleado a un campo en la tabla teléfonos y al consultar haría un left join, pero en este caso pretendo que dos tablas compartan la tabla teléfonos. Necesito sugerencias por favor.

[image: Tabla empleados]

[image: Tabla áreas]

[image: Tabla telefonos]

Comment: Todo depende de como se relacionen estos teléfonos con los empleados y/o areas. Los empleados podran tener un telefono ? o mas de uno ?. Igual pregunta para las areas ?

Comment: Los empleados y las áreas pueden tener uno o varios teléfonos, por eso no quiero hacer una columna de teléfonos en la tabla empleados porque pueden ser varios teléfonos y una sola columna no me serviría, igual en la tabla áreas pueden haber áreas con uno o diez teléfonos

Comment: Estaba pensando agregar una columna tanto en empleados como en áreas y crear allí un identificador unico, algo así como un md5, formado a partir del id, y quizá la palabra 'area' o 'empleado'

Comment: y un telefono puede pertenecer a mas de un empleado/area ?

Comment: Anibal, no, solo puede pertenecer a un empleado/area.

Comment: yo te aconsejaria, una llave (idTelefono) en las tablas y empleado y area. Y en la tabla Telefono agregaria una columna adicional 'tipo' (EMPLEADO, AREA).

Comment: Porque querrias una sola tabla de telefonos? no se que tendran que ver area y empleados, pero por mas que los datos sean telefonos, parecen telefonos que deberian ir totalmente en otra tabla. No hay relacion entre ellos..

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tener una tabla padre de la cual extiendan Empleados y Áreas, como en el ejemplo de AdventureWorks de MSSQL ([En esta respuesta de SOen puedes leer una explicación](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13222125/6658955)) donde existe un `BusinessEntity` que evita la redundancia. No estoy seguro de que MySql soporte herencia de tablas ([leer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36577/169541)) Al menos en las versiones que trabajé no lo hacía de la forma que MSSQL y PostgreSQL lo hacen.

De todas formas, queda así:

```
Table Contact (
PK  id
    contact_type
    contact_data
    // este es el id del empleado o del area, que es único por la herencia
FK  owner_id 
)
```

Puedes ahondar en la estructura entidadNegocio<-empleado, entidadNegocio<-area mirando los [diagramas del modelo](https://www.google.com/search?q=adventureworks%20schema) del ejemplo que te mencioné.

Otra forma de hacerlo, es agregar un campo que indique el dueño del contacto (empleado o area). En este caso se pierden las ventajas de las FKs (ej: los deletes en cascada).

```
Table Contact (
PK  id int
    contact_type
    contact_data

    owner_type enum ('employee', 'area')
    owner_id
)
```

La columna `owner_type` puede ser un [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) de MySql para aumentar la velocidad de las consultas. En este caso los joins tienen ambas condiciones:

```
select *
from Employee as e
join Contact as c on c.owner_type = 'employee' and c.owner_id = e.id
```

En esta segunda opción, las validaciones se deben hacer por software